# Regex to match different symbols same number of times in various part of text

Tags: python, regex, bioinformatics

I need to parse Newick format that is useful for trees. It looks like series of brackets, commas and letters denoted nodes:

```
(A,B,(C,D)E)F
```

or, for another example:

```
(,(((,(,)),),))
```

`(,)` element means nodes with same parent. For my purpose (to measure a path length between two leafs) I need consequentially to look for such nested elements.

So, my question is how to match different symbols same number of times?

For example, I want to match `AB` pattern in string:

```
CCCAAABBACCCABCCAAABBBBBBACCCCCABBBABBCCAABB
```

Regex should return: `['AABB','AB','AAABBB','AB','AB','AABB']`

Every time the number of repetition is different. So `A{n}B{n}` doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: If you can speak Perl, this may be useful: http://edwards.sdsu.edu/labsite/index.php/robs/375-parsing-newick-trees

Comment: This is not regular, and Python regexes don't support recursion, so you can't do it with a regex alone.

Comment: Would you want to match `AABB` within `**AABBB**` or within `**AAABB**`?

Comment: I think you should `findAll( r"A+B+", "g" )` then filter the match result.

Comment: I just want to know if there is a regexp solution. But thanks.

Comment: `**AABBB**` means proper match. I tried to highlight this part of code. I doesn't know markup yet.

Comment: Usually when you hear "nested" or "recursion", then regex is not the way to go. Only very few regex flavors can handle recursion at all, and RDPs are almost always a better approach even then.

Comment: It might be worth checking this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195374/python-for-loop-iteration

Comment: @TimPietzcker the [regex](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module supports recursive regexes and is likely to become a part of the Python stl in the post-3.3 time frame. BorisKovarski, [here](http://adam.sardar.me.uk/?p=583) is a blog post about parsing Newick trees with Perls' recursive regexes. Perhaps you could adapt the same approach to Python with the help of the regex module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is classic example what regular expressions **can't** do.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages in section "Use of lemma" there is prove that language "a^nb^n" is not regular (so it can't be recognized by regular expressions).

Using regular expression you can only create regular expressions for a given maximum `n`. But expression for large `n` can take long to evaluate.

PS. Your problem can be solved using Formal grammars (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar) or Counter automaton (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter_automaton).

Answer (score 0):

**Example: Parenthesis simplification**

Assume O = opening parenthesis, C = closing parenthesis, and X = some expression in-between.

In some cases, we can only simplify if the number of O present on left-side matches the same count of C on the right-side.

We can still use RegExp here:

Put the rx in a loop and only match pairs of one O and one C, repeatedly operating on the output of the previous loop until it is fully reduced/decomposed.

```
const EXAMPLES =
`
OC
OOOOCOCCOCXCC
X
OCX
OXC
OOXCC
OOXXCC
OXOXXCC
OOXCOXXCC
OXCOXC
OXXCOXXC
`;

const is = v=>null!=v;
for (let input of EXAMPLES.trim().split(/\r?\n/g)) {
    console.log('input', JSON.stringify(input));
    let replaced;
    do {
        replaced = false;
        input = input.replace(/(?:OC|O(X)C|^(O{1,99})(X{1,99}(?:O{1,99}X{1,99}){0,99})(C{1,99})$)/gm, (...m) => {
            replaced = true;
            let out, clen;
            debugger;
            console.log(' m', JSON.stringify(m));
            if (is(m[2])) {
                clen = Math.min(m[2].length, m[4].length);
                out = m[2].substr(clen) + m[3] + m[4].substr(clen);
            }
            else {
                out = m.slice(1,-2).map(v=>null==v?'':v).join('');
            }
            console.log(' replaceWith', JSON.stringify(out));
            return out;
        });
    } while (replaced);
    console.log('output', JSON.stringify(input)+'\n')
}
```

**Output:**

```
input "OC"
 m ["OC",null,null,null,null,0,"OC"]
 replaceWith ""
output ""

input "OOOOCOCCOCXCC"
 m ["OC",null,null,null,null,3,"OOOOCOCCOCXCC"]
 replaceWith ""
 m ["OC",null,null,null,null,5,"OOOOCOCCOCXCC"]
 replaceWith ""
 m ["OC",null,null,null,null,8,"OOOOCOCCOCXCC"]
 replaceWith ""
 m ["OC",null,null,null,null,2,"OOOCXCC"]
 replaceWith ""
 m ["OOXCC",null,"OO","X","CC",0,"OOXCC"]
 replaceWith "X"
output "X"

input "X"
output "X"

input "OCX"
 m ["OC",null,null,null,null,0,"OCX"]
 replaceWith ""
output "X"

input "OXC"
 m ["OXC","X",null,null,null,0,"OXC"]
 replaceWith "X"
output "X"

input "OOXCC"
 m ["OOXCC",null,"OO","X","CC",0,"OOXCC"]
 replaceWith "X"
output "X"

input "OOXXCC"
 m ["OOXXCC",null,"OO","XX","CC",0,"OOXXCC"]
 replaceWith "XX"
output "XX"

input "OXOXXCC"
 m ["OXOXXCC",null,"O","XOXX","CC",0,"OXOXXCC"]
 replaceWith "XOXXC"
output "XOXXC"

input "OOXCOXXCC"
 m ["OXC","X",null,null,null,1,"OOXCOXXCC"]
 replaceWith "X"
 m ["OXOXXCC",null,"O","XOXX","CC",0,"OXOXXCC"]
 replaceWith "XOXXC"
output "XOXXC"

input "OXCOXC"
 m ["OXC","X",null,null,null,0,"OXCOXC"]
 replaceWith "X"
 m ["OXC","X",null,null,null,3,"OXCOXC"]
 replaceWith "X"
output "XX"

input "OXXCOXXC"
output "OXXCOXXC"
```